# How to Merge 2 same rows into single row having only one column difference using Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to merge below 2 records into single row using Azure data flows

| Account Number | Phone type | Home Number | Mobile Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Home | 989 324 1234 |  |
| 1234 | Mobile |  | 9893238893 |

Required OutPut

| Account Number | Home Number | Mobile Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 989 324 1234 | 989 323 8893 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NULL` values will be holded in the empty columns, you can simply use a `max` function in an `aggregate` activity to achieve the expected behaviour.

Test case I used, an inline dataset:

```sql
SELECT 1234 AS accountNumber, 'Home' AS phoneType, '989 324 1234' AS homeNumber, null AS mobileNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT 1234 AS accountNumber, 'Mobile' AS phoneType, null AS homeNumber, '9893238893' AS mobileNumber
```

The aggregate stage:
[image]

[image]

Result in data preview:
[image]

Complete json for the dataflow:

```json
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "azuresqluat1",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "Aggregate1"
                }
            ],
            "script": "source(output(\n\t\taccountNumber as integer,\n\t\tphoneType as string,\n\t\thomeNumber as string,\n\t\tmobileNumber as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'query',\n\tstore: 'sqlserver',\n\tquery: 'SELECT 1234 AS accountNumber, \\'Home\\' AS phoneType, \\'989 324 1234\\' AS homeNumber, \\'\\' AS mobileNumber\\nUNION ALL\\nSELECT 1234 AS accountNumber, \\'Mobile\\' AS phoneType, \\'\\' AS homeNumber, \\'9893238893\\' AS mobileNumber',\n\tisolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED') ~> source1\nsource1 aggregate(groupBy(accountNumber),\n\thomeNumber = max(homeNumber),\n\t\tmobileNumber = max(mobileNumber)) ~> Aggregate1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Ray, I tried using your suggestion but it didnt worked for me. The Input values are string datatype and i converted to Integer and applied Max() on top of it but not resulting any values.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current trial? You should not need to convert it to integer first before applying max as the collation should be able to treat the phone numbers larger than null values